# Material-UI: Too many re-renders. The layout is unstable. TextareaAutosize limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following piece of code:

```
export function MyTextField({ onChange, defaultValue }) {
  return (
    <TextField
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      onChange={(event) => {
        if (onChange) {
          onChange(event.target.value);
        } else {
          console.log("*no onChange function added*", event.target.value);
        }
      }}
    />
  );
}

//then I use MyTextField in another component

const [recommendations, setRecommendations] = useState(
   (appointment.recommendations) || ""
)
console.log(recommendations) // logs as expected with every onChange

<MyTextField
   defaultValue={recommendations}
   onChange={setRecommendations}
/>
```

After some 10 or more 'onChange' happen, I get this error on the console:

```
Material-UI: Too many re-renders. The layout is unstable.
TextareaAutosize limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

I've read other SO questions suggesting I use a arrow function but I don't think I did this right because the error persists.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I faced a similar issue.
In my case,
`multiline={true}` is causing this error. And I found following two approaches would remove that warning.

1. set `multiline={false}`
2. if `multiline={true}`, then set `rows={some number}`
   to avoid re-rendering of element itself in addition to data.

Comment: Option 2 works for me. Fun fact `multiline={true}` and `maxRows={some number}` did not work

Comment: Option 2 does not work for me. Still renders too many times even when rows are defined.

Comment: One of the main benefits of MUI multiline TextField is its autosize features. Unfortunately, setting rows stop it auto resizing (as expected). I found out that setting both `minRows` and `maxRows` solves the problem (at least for me).

Answer (score 9):

I found the answer to this actually wasn't anything to do with your code actually doing updates. It's MUI not being able to find stable dimensions for the TextField when using the multiline parameter, as there are too many variables.

In my case it was a TextField with pretty much infinite space around it; MUI didn't know whether to make the input wide or tall!

So I fixed it by using the fullWidth parameter; so it was effectively constrained in a direction.

I hope that helps someone :)

Comment: I had to add maxRows to avoid the error as well.  The field component was within an Accordion

Comment: Setting `fullWidth` had no effect for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I need a controlled input so I have to use value and onChange. The best solution that worked for me was disabling React's strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer suggests to define the `rows` property if you want multiline.

That solves the issue, and if you don't want (or need) that the textarea resizes according to its contents, it will be fine.

Unfortunately, if you want that the `TextField` keeps its autosize features, setting `rows` is not a valid solution.

I found out that setting both `minRows` and `maxRows` solves the problem (at least for my case).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and defining maxRows/minRows did not work.

I was using useForm to fill in default value's, but manually setting the defaultValue is what did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with reacthookform and its register method. Using the controller instead of `{...register("field")}` seems to solve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You face an issue with controlled/uncontrolled components. [Read this article for more details](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). You should change 'defaultValue' to simply 'value' to make it work properly.

```
export function MyTextField({ onChange, value }) {
  return (
    <TextField
      value={value}
      onChange={(event) => {
        if (onChange) {
          onChange(event.target.value);
        } else {
          console.log("*no onChange function added*", event.target.value);
        }
      }}
    />
  );
}

const [recommendations, setRecommendations] = useState(
   (appointment.recommendations) || "defaultValueYouNeed"
)

<MyTextField
   value={recommendations}
   onChange={setRecommendations}
/>
```

Comment: this didn't work. apart from the same problem still happening, now I can't get a default value showing (meaning it's pre-filled.)

Comment: If you need a default value, you should set it in state. You should either use value+onChange or defaultValue without handler.

Comment: could you provide a more thorough code example? a edit in your answer would be great

Comment: that's exactly what I tried but the problem has not been solved. "appointment.recommendations" is already the default value I need. Tried both value and defaultValue (with and without handler)