# Too many re-renders. The layout is unstable. TextareaAutosize limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a multiline TextField defined in the following way:

```
<TextField
  id="outlined-multiline-flexible"
  label="Description"
  multiline
  rows={10}
  value={description}
  onChange={handleChangeDescription}
/>
```

Here is the `handleChangeDescription`:

```js
function handleChangeDescription(event: { target: { value: SetStateAction<string> } }) {
  setDescription(event.target.value)     
}
```

I know it's basically correct because I got it directly from the MaterialUI docs pretty much, but I keep getting the same error: "Material UI: Too many re-renders. The layout is unstable. TextareaAutosize limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop".

Weirdly, this only happens when I render the page, then click off from the page, and then click back onto it. The error doesn't show up on the initial render. I'm really not sure what I can do to solve it. I already tried everything in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64837884/material-ui-too-many-re-renders-the-layout-is-unstable-textareaautosize-limit) thread and nothing helped, so I really would appreciate any additional suggestions!!